# Проблема при создании icq бота на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, icq

Проблема при создании бота для icq на python с библиотекой mailru-im-bot

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\SuperMSI\Desktop\from bot.py", line 1, in 
from bot.bot import Bot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot'

Всё установлено верно пробовал разные методы не помогает. Помогите если сможете

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что модуль не найден, значит в настройках или процессе установки возникли проблемы. Надо проверять настройки python, что модуль установился и виден окружением.

Comment: Проверил всё установлено верно есть ли другие варианты ошибки?